# Cannot save new object in one to one relationship using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following django classes:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, related_name='cal_event')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='events')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateTimeField('event date')
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, through='EventRoles')

    class Meta:
      db_table = "event"
      unique_together = ("date", "department")


class EventId(models.Model):
    event = models.OneToOneField(Event, primary_key=True, related_name='event_number')
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
      db_table = "event_id"
```

The django rest serializer class for EventId is as follows:

```
class EventIdS(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = EventId
```

Now whenever I try to save a new `EventId` object, the code fails at the instance of saving it. For example:

```
def put(self, request, event_pk, format=None):
    # Get an existing event object 
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_pk)

    # Get id number from ajax request
    event_id = request.data.get('id', None)

    if event_id:
      db_data = {
        'event' : event.id,
        'number' : event_id
      }

      idSerial = EventIdS(event, data=db_data)

      if idSerial.is_valid():
        eventID = event.event_number
        eventID.number = event_id
        eventID.save()
```

The code fails at `eventID.save()` and I don't know why. Whenever I print `event_id`, it is a long number (example: 12L). What am I missing? Any ideas will be gladly welcomed.

Comment: Please add a full stacktrace of the error if you can obtain one.

Comment: What version of `DRF` are you using?  In the docs here it says to call the `update()` differently: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: I think your `event_id` is fine. I dont think you need to pass the `event` object when initialising the `EventIdS` serializer. So it should be somthing like this: `idSerial = EventIdS(data=db_data)`. Although, ideally you should include full stacktrace in you question, making it easier for us to debug.

Comment: @mishbah He trying to perform a partial update, so he needs to pass event instance.

Comment: @AronYsidoro my version of DRF is 3.0.5.

Comment: It's just as @mishbah pointed out. I am trying to do a partial update of the EventId object. Maybe I need to pass an exisiting EventId object to be updated and not an Event object.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `.save()` over `idSerial` first, it will returns `eventID` updated instance, then you can set number attribute then save it.

```
 idSerial = EventIdS(event, data=db_data)
 if idSerial.is_valid():

    eventID = idSerial.save()
    eventID.number = event_id
    eventID.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, I was missing the updated instance. Got it.

Comment: However the `eventID.number` is not updated with the new number in the db.

Comment: That is the new number attribute is not updated in the db, although it is updated in the current `eventID` and `event` object.